# Drag drop or sortable with select all and multiple functionality

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I want the same thing which is shown in following demo with 2-3 additional features.

**This demo is created by "Fudgey" a member of stackoverflow.**

http://jsfiddle.net/T68Fn/

1. I want a button or link (select all) to select all the boxes so that I can drag all the boxes and drop them in next/bottom list.
2. I want to place boxes any where in list. Do not want to appendTo/prependTo.
3. Can select multiple boxes with the help or ctrl/alt/shift key. I know it is very well working on click but for user benefit. I want to add this functionality.

Last thing when I copy and paste whole demo (http://jsfiddle.net/T68Fn/) in an html, its shown me a script error in first line "$(document).ready(function()" that "$" is not define.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

well i am goin to answer for the last thing, the reason you are getting error is probably you haven't included the jquery in your page add the following line and you'll be good to go...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already try with including the latest jquery file. but it is not working. Please try and let me know.

Comment: you will also have to include the `jquery UI` library